# How get select item from a spinner and change image if a specific item is selected?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i want to get selected item from a spinner, and if, for example, `Table 2` is selected, i want to change a `ImageView`'s `src` to another image. here's what i've tried so far:

```
public class Tables extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tables);
    Spinner dropdown = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.q1);
    String[] items = new String[]{"Table 1", "Table 2"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
    dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
    String text = dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if (text.equals("Table 1"))
    {
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (text.equals("Table 2")){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.i2);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to register a listener on `dropdown` for item being clicked or the selection changing events, and then read the selection from the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something like this to listen what was selected:

```
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                String items = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();


                if (items.equals("Table 1")){
                   imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else if (items.equals("Table 2") {

                   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.i2); 

                }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });
```